# Unable to load all styles from bootstrap-sass gem - Rails 5.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4, sprockets

I'm trying to create a Bootstrap navbar using `gem "bootstrap-sass"` but it isn't loading like expected.

This is the navbar fully loaded, available on bootstrap's website:

[image: Navbar as it should appear]

After following the tutorial available [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) (and after failing, many others), I still get the same result, which is a navbar with just a few bootstrap classes loaded:

[image: Navbar as it is appeaing]

If we take a closer look at the css classes modifying the "Search" button, we notice that the `btn` class is taking effect, but the class `btn-outline-success` is not loaded properly.

I've already tried to remove `*= require_tree .` and `*= require_self` or to keep them, but the result is always the same.

The JavaScript seems to be working because the drop-down menu seems to have the expected behavior.

I would like to know what's missing to get all the css classes loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already renamed your application.css to application.scss and imported the relevant styles? If not, make sure to do so, as the [docs](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) suggest:

```
//"bootstrap-sprockets" must be imported before "bootstrap" and "bootstrap/variables"
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: Yes, I did exactly like that, but this method isn't enabling some styles. I think there is something else to configure...

Answer (score 0):

The source of the issue you are facing is actually explained at the beginning of the README there:

> `bootstrap-sass` is a Sass-powered version of Bootstrap 3

And the next sentence says:

> This is Bootstrap 3. **For Bootstrap 4 use the [Bootstrap Ruby gem](http://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem) if you use Ruby, and the [main repo](http://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) otherwise.**

You see, you've been trying to get a Bootstrap 4 navbar by loading Bootstrap 3 files.

That's not gonna work. Bootstrap 4 needs Bootstrap 4 files.

Also, keep in mind that Bootstrap 4 is very different from Bootstrap 3. So, a Bootstrap 3 theme (as an example) is gonna be completely incompatible with Bootstrap 4 and vice versa.

So, if you load these files here (in that order):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

...then your Bootstrap 4 navbar is gonna look "like new".